# firebase login function not running

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to run the login function for firebase, which worked fine, but after updating swift version it doesn't work.  When I check both if the error is nil and not nil neither print statement runs, but the prints before and after does.  Does anyone know why this would not be running, but also not throwing error?

Below is the code:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
    if error == nil {

        print("Successful login")

        if user!.isEmailVerified {
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as! ProfileView
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            print("nil is hitting")
        }
    }
})
print("done running login")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Auth instead of FIRAuth.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

To know more read 
[Firebase Documention](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

Comment: This just gives me the following error: `use of unresolved identifier Auth`

Comment: This is probable because you don't have updated version of firebase. update your firebase using cocopods.

Answer (score 0):

To `signIn` in **Firebase**, you need to use `Auth` instead `FIRAuth`

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "email@email.com", 
                    password: "123456") { (user, error) in

    if error == nil {
        print("successful login")   
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error { print("Enter Valid email and password")
                }else{
                 if Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified == true{
                 let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as! ProfileView
                 self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)}}}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error: `use of unresolved identified "Auth"` on the first line

Comment: you have to just do this -- import FirebaseAuth

Comment: @Drew install the latest version of Firebase and the error should be resolved. From the code I can see that you are not using the latest version (FIR prefix was removed in newer versions of Firebase)
EDIT: Before running "pod install" make sure you update cocoapods version with: "sudo gem install cocoapods"